# convert bullet numbers to a integer in excel

Tags: excel

I am required to convert a bullet number in one column of excel to an integer:

Here is the example I'm trying to show:

```
3       =  3000000
3.1     =  3010000
3.1.1   =  3010100
3.1.1.1 =  3010101
10.1    = 10010000
```

I'm having issues because the bullets do not all have the same number of characters.

Substitute commands only replace all or none.
Is there a in-line way to convert the bullets to numbers like this?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes.  Convert the dot to a zero.  The number of trailing zeros to add is related to the number of dots. 0 dots is 6 trailing zeros, 1 dot is 4, 2 dots is 2 trailing zeros, and 3 dots has none.

Answer (score 0):

Not an ideal answer - I'm sure there's better ways, but using dev1998 explanation this will work:

> =SUBSTITUTE(A1,".","0") & REPT("0",CHOOSE(LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,".",""))+1,6,4,2,0))

Broken down into separate functions:
Replace the decimal point with 0:

> **In C1:** =SUBSTITUTE(A1,".","0")

How many trailing zeros:

> **In D1** =CHOOSE(LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,".",""))+1,6,4,2,0)

Trailing zeros:

> **In E1:** =REPT("0",D1)

Stick it all together:

> **In F1:** = C1 & E1

Comment: Thank you so much Darren,  I've been working on your guys solution. However, if I have 3.10.1, it should read 3100100, but it reads
30100100.  Thanks.

Comment: Not sure how the logic works then - 3.1.1 is ok with 3010100, but shouldn't it then be 310100?